# Using window.onclick more than once cause issues in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React application with menu opens from left and three modals and I need to handle clicking outside them. At first I was handling the modal using `window.onclick`  and every thing works fine ; After I do the same for the Menu It cause some issues and kind of conflict with each other ; In some clicks they don't react as expected and don't close or open.
Any ideas for this?

Comment: You need to use a ref to exclude clicks that aren't inside the element. If you search Google for "useClickOutside" you'll find lots of existing implementations of this in custom hooks.

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful.